How to remove a second search text on tvOS18?
I have an issue on tvOS 18 beta from Aug 20, where the search text is displayed twice, as in the image below.

Code to reproduce the behavior is trivial:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Some content...")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
   }
}

I did not find anything new in the API or documentation to disable it. Also, online searches for this specific issue did not produce any results.
I would like to show the same behavior on tvOS18, as on tvOS17, without the second search text.
Any idea on how to hide that second search text?

have you tried using NavigationStack instead of the deprecated NavigationView?

Unfortunately, the same behavior is observed.
